Use Lua lfs to detect symlink?
My workflow involves contributions from others. They are instructed to place all their content in a single top-level folder (which may contain sub-folders). Their main document must be at their top level, and may only include material parallel to, or in a subfolder relative to, their main document. In other words, no absolute paths, and no ../ to jump out of their top-level folder.
At my end, I re-define \include{} so that it throws an error if the included material has a path beginning with / or ../ (we use Linux).
Unfortunately, if the contributor uses a symlink to external material, the \include{} simply follows the symlink, and the above path detection does not work. Then, when the folder is sent to me, something is missing.
I see that Lua has an lfs module, and it is mentioned in the LuaTeX manual. I can also grep for "symlink" in texmf-dist/tex/luatex and see that it is mentioned in code. Presumably, compiling with lualatex allows the possibility use lfs to test whether or not something is a symlink, and fork depending on the result. The kpse library does not seem to have that capability.
Sadly, I am not enough of a programmer to figure this out for myself. Looks like I need to do something vaguely like this:
\directlua{
  a=lfs.attribute(something that detects symlink)
  if a then
    this routine
  else
    that routine
  end
}

Any suggestions? I imagine that others might also be interested.
EDIT: Marcel answered the question (accepted). If security is also an issue, have a look at David's comment just below this.
The complete solution, based on Marcel's code:
\def\checksymlink#1{%
  \directlua{
    if 'link' == lfs.symlinkattributes("\luaescapestring{#1}", 'mode') then
      texio.write_nl("\luaescapestring{#1} is a symlink")
    else
      texio.write_nl("\luaescapestring{#1} is not a symlink")
    end
  }%
}

The above prints messages to Terminal. It is also possible to change
the "is a symlink" message to an error or warning, which would be more prominent.

"At my end, I re-define \include{} so that it throws an error if the included material has a path beginning with / or ../ (we use Linux)." much more secure than doing that in tex macros is to set open_in = p in your texmf.cnf % p (paranoid)   : as ``r' and disallow going to parent directories, and  restrict absolute paths to be under $TEXMFOUTPUT.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

@DavidCarlisle That is useful for me (as recipient of the content). However, the contributors cannot modify their own texmf.cnf and do not need to do that, because they do net receive content from others. What I need is something that I can put in the templates, so that the symlink error is thrown at the provider's end, before the files are sent to me.

You do not want to use lfs.attributes for this since that function follows symlinks, so it will report the attributes of the target of the symlink and not the symlink itself. (Of course, that's never a symlink because if it would have been it would have been followed). This makes it tricky to look a attributes of symlinks, therefore a second function lfs.symlinkattributes exists to get attributes of a file without following symlinks, so reporting information about the link instead of the target of the link.
With this, you can use
if 'link' == lfs.symlinkattributes("some_path", 'mode') then
  texio.write_nl("some_path is a symlink")
else
  texio.write_nl("some_path is not a symlink")
end


I will have a look at that, and report back. Seems like the right kind of thing.
